# What are the appropriate configurations for the Subdomain module on Window 7 running XAMPP?

Tags: 6, subsites

I have installed the Subdomain module (v 6.1.7), and I'm configuring a subdomain for testing on localhost.

I have been tearing my hair out for days now, trying to get this module to work on my PC - and I'm still stuck on the settings/configuration stage. I have scoured the web for help in vain, and now I'm appealing for help here.

My vital stats: Win7, XAMPP, Drupal 6, Subdomain 6.17. (I gave up on 6.2 because it turned my links into www.localhost/....)

My site is localhost/ideastar.

Here are the changes I have made:

#### settings.php

```
$cookie_domain = '';
```

Leaving this commented out gives me an error ("The $cookie_domain variable in settings.php is not set".)

Uncommenting and putting in "localhost", ".localhost",  "ideastar", ".ideastar" gives me an "Access denied" error.

It seems to accept "localhost/ideastar" or a blank ' ',  although I don't know if this is the right thing to do.

#### host

```
127.0.1.1   localhost  ideastar
```

(and I can successfully ping ideastar)

#### http.conf

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName ideaster
ServerAlias *.ideastar
DocumentRoot C:/xampp/htdocs
</VirtualHost>
```

Can someone please help me get past the following errors?

#### Subdomain Prerequisites

> To enable subdomains on your website, you must first configure the following 5 items. If something isn't working, refer to the suggested solutions and make sure you have completed each step outlined in readme.txt.
>
> DNS server show/hide details: Not working yet
>   test-1.localhost: Failed to resolve
>   test-2.localhost: Failed to resolve
>   test-3.localhost: Failed to resolve
>
> It appears your DNS server is not setup to handle wildcard subdomains (*.localhost) for localhost. Edit the DNS zone file or settings for your server to fix.
>
> PHP caches DNS lookups, so you'll want to restart your web server after making changes to your DNS server to see the results of your changes on this page.
>
> Web server: Unable to test
>   Unable to test Apache settings until DNS wildcard subdomains are working
>   Drupal's inbound URL rewriting - show/hide details: Not working yet
>   HTTP request to http://subdomain-test.localhost/ideally/subdomain/test resulted in an internal Drupal path of . It should have been ~subdomain-test/subdomain/test
>   The `custom_url_rewrite_inbound()` function in settings.php is rewriting the internal path incorrectly. Did you patch settings.php? See readme.txt for instructions.
>
> Drupal's outbound URL rewriting - show/hide details: Working
>   Drupal API: url('~subdomain-test/subdomain/test') returned 'http://subdomain-test.localhost/ideally/subdomain/test'
>   $cookie_domain in settings.php - show/hide details: Set
>   The $cookie_domain variable in settings.php is set to ''

Comment: `$cookie_domain = '';` might actually be wrong. have you tried to set it to the actual local dev url? also, many browsers aggressively cache these configs and redirects, are you using a browser and/ or plugin to really erase the browser cache?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to setup a *virtual host* in *XAMPP* having a different IP, like `127.0.1.2` and adjust your *host file* by adding `127.0.1.2` sub.ideastar.

More [here](http://sio-web.blogspot.com/2011/03/xammp-localhost-und-subdomains.html) (but in german.)

Comment: I tried the solution suggested in the link - and the errors remained the same. <1>I forgot to mention that I would like to use subdomain with Ogranic Groups; so I need to be able to use a wildcard. I just don't know how.  <2> What do I put in the $cookie_domain variable in the settings.phph file?